# Empty string to nullable type conversion using Automapper 3.0?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to convert properties on source object of strings to destination object properties of nullable datatypes(int?,bool?,DateTime?). properties of type string on my source can be empty and when they are empty an equivalent null should be mapped on destination property.It works fine when property has value but when it is empty
It throws an exception {"String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."}

```
public class SourceTestString
{
  public string IsEmptyString {get; set;}
}

public class DestinationTestBool
{
  public bool? IsEmptyString {get; set;}
}
```

My Converter class

```
public class StringToNullableBooleanConverter : ITypeConverter<string,bool?>
 {
     public bool? Convert(ResolutionContext context) 
     {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Convert.ToString(context.SourceValue)) ||  String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.Convert.ToString(context.SourceValue)))
         {
            return default(bool?);
         }
         else
         {
            return bool.Parse(context.SourceValue.ToString()); 
         }
      }
  }
```

Create Map

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<string,bool?>().ConvertUsing(new StringToNullableBooleanConverter());
```

Map Method

```
SourceTestString source = SourceTestString();
source.IsEmptyString = ""; 
var destination = Mapper.Map<SourceTestString,DestinationTestBool>(source);
```

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` works for empty values as well - you shouldn't need both checks.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I'll take it but it does not solve my problem though :(

Comment: It works fine for me. What version of AutoMapper are you using?

Comment: Is it working for empty string? I'm using Automapper 3.0.

Comment: @Mightymuke Thank you very much! your comment has enlighten me and solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, The Code in my question working perfectly. It was one of my properties which was bool instead of bool? and I apologize for that and thanks for one and all for participation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class StringToNullableBooleanConverter : 
    ITypeConverter<string, bool?>
{
    public bool? Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Convert.ToString(context.SourceValue)) 
            || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.Convert.ToString(context.SourceValue)))
        {
            return default(bool?);
        }
        else
        {
            bool? boolValue=null;
            bool evalBool;
            if (bool.TryParse(context.SourceValue.ToString(), out evalBool))
            {
                boolValue = evalBool;
            }
            return boolValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar still its not working.                                                bool boolValue = false;
return bool.TryParse(context.SourceValue.ToString(),out boolValue) ? boolValue : default(bool?);